# Listen to ngrx Actions from Component

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm building an app using ngrx/angular8, and there is one scenario where i want to respond to an action from different components. The traditional way is to add another property to the store and create the reducer/selector for it. Problem is I want for the other components to respond to the event even if it has the same value. e.g. lets break down:

1. I clicked on a button in one of the components, it dispatches the action `this.store.dispatch( LayoutActions.scrollToSession({id: session_id})`
2. I want 3 different component to respond to this action in some way, even if the `session_id` is the same. So If i created a property in the reducer, the selector will get the update only for the first time and won't fire for subsequent actions.

My solution was simply to dispatch the action, and in the component im listening for the action:

```
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(LayoutActions.scrollToSession),
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
        ).subscribe(id => { 

            if ((!id.id) || (!this.messages_list)) return;
            this.messages_list.scrollToElement(`#session-${id.id}`, {left: null, top: null});

        });
```

My question is, is this the right approach? listening for the actions in the components directly and what are my alternatives if any? I though of adding a random prefix when dispatch the action, to change the store state and remove it later in the selector, but that doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***UPDATED***

The right way is to always rely on the store state, not on its actions.

possible solution

store.ts

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Actions, createEffect, ofType} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {Action, createAction, createFeatureSelector, createReducer, createSelector, on, props} from '@ngrx/store';
import {delay, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

// actions
export const setScroll = createAction('scroll', props<{id?: string, shaker?: number}>());
export const causeTask = createAction('task', props<{scrollId: string}>());

// reducer
export interface State {
    scroll?: {
        id: string,
        shaker: number,
    };
}

const reducer = createReducer(
    {},

    on(setScroll, (state, {id, shaker}) => ({
        ...state,
        scroll: id ? {id, shaker} : undefined,
    })),
);

export function coreReducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    return reducer(state, action);
}

export const selectState = createFeatureSelector<State>('core');

export const selectFlag = createSelector(
    selectState,
    state => state.scroll,
);

// effects
@Injectable()
export class Effects  {
    public readonly effect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(causeTask),
        delay(5000),
        map(({scrollId}) => setScroll({id: scrollId, shaker: Math.random()})),
    ));

    constructor(protected readonly actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {causeTask, selectFlag, setScroll} from 'src/app/store';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(protected store: Store) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        // reset of the scrolling state
        this.store.dispatch(setScroll({}));

        this.store.select(selectFlag).pipe(
            filter(f => !!f),
            map(f => f.id),
        ).subscribe(value => {
            this.store.dispatch(setScroll({})); // reset
            alert(value); // <- here you should use the scrolling.
        });

        // some long task which result should cause scrolling to id.id.
        this.store.dispatch(causeTask({scrollId: 'value of id.id'}));
        this.store.dispatch(causeTask({scrollId: 'value of id.id'}));
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {EffectsModule} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {coreReducer, Effects} from 'src/app/store';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
      StoreModule.forRoot({
        core: coreReducer,
      }),
      EffectsModule.forRoot([
        Effects,
      ]),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***ORIGINAL***

If you need the actions you can use their stream.

```js
import {StoreActions, StoreState} from '@core/store';


...
    constructor(
        protected readonly storeActions: StoreActions,
    ) {}
...

...
        // listening on success action of company change request.
        this.storeActions
            .ofType(CompanyProfileActions.UpdateBaseSuccess)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe();
...
```

Comment: yea that’s what i’m currently doing, but is it good practice to listen from the component directly ?

Comment: it is the latest thing anyone should do :) right way is to use ngrx/effects and to update state with loading flags, async tasks progress etc.

Comment: , yea i do this for all the global notifications, but i can’t really access the component elements from the effect

Comment: right, totally understand you because it looks a bit overwhelmed. the flow should be next - you have a state for the scrolling flag that is set to false or anything negative in ngOnInit. then you have a select from store of the flag unit it is something positive (for example the `id.id`. and in its subscribe you call `scrollToElement`. The related effect should dispatch an action that sets the flag to the id. Then you can avoid a direct listener to the store actions.

Comment: not quite following can you elaborate on the flow please thanks

Comment: sure. I'll try to create a code sample and update my answer. I'll drop a message here once it has been done.

Comment: Done. you can check the answer. if you run the code in 5 seconds you'll get the alert of the desired id for the scrolling.

Comment: so the problem is now, lets say I dispatched the action         `this.store.dispatch(causeTask({scrollId: 5}));`, and I listened for the selector in the component. And then after 1 minute, I dispatched the same action with the same id value ` this.store.dispatch(causeTask({scrollId: 5}));`, now the problems lies in that the selector won't trigger, because it's the same value (5),  although i need to react on it even if it's the same

Comment: then simply add with the id a random key to shake the store.

Comment: actually `this.store.dispatch(setScroll({}));` in subscribe does the job without the shaker.

Comment: fair enough, so dispatching two actions to shake the store

Comment: yeah, to verify it brings 2 alerts.